# How I can create an extension method for asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How I can create an extension method like "Html.DisplayTextFor" in Asp.net mvc ? I mean I need an extension for my page class in asp.net like "Page.DisplayTextFor" how I can implement it. I have created this :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace System.Web.UI
    {
        public static class PageExtension
        {
            public static void DisplayTextFor(this string text)
            {
              /*some operation*/
            }
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to use the HtmlHelper class as the extension parameter, not string.

Comment: I wouldn't put it in a system namespace. Just put it in your own. I don't see why this wouldn't create an extension function on string. so you could write `"hi".DisplayTextFor()`

Comment: You have created an extension method for `string` not for `System.Web.UI.Page`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean you want to extend the Page class adding your own functions to appear when using `this.Page...`?

If so, first have the `PageExtension` class as part of **your own** namespace. Then the syntax is:

```
public static void DisplayTextFor(this Page page, string text)
{
    page.Response.Write(text);
}
```

The extension method first parameter defines what class to extend, the rest of the parameters define what you send when calling it.

To call the above from within your page, just have:

```
this.Page.DisplayTextFor("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pick an existing property in the `System.Web.UI.Page` class to extend, or create your own property (in a base class) and your own class.